# How to make a any node as parent node in JTree so that children can be added to it?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

How to make current node in JTree as parent node so as to add children to it. My complete data are fetched from the database.

somewhat like below :

```
root-- parent1 - children
    |- parent2 - children
```

I need to dynamically generate the tree

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If your nodes are MutableTreeNode e.g. DefaultMutableTreeNode use

```
public void insert(MutableTreeNode newChild, int childIndex)
```

method to add children to current node

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to construct a tree is to construct a hierarchy of [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) instances. This class has an `add(MutableTreeNode newChild)` method which allows adding a child to an existing node.